# C: add all the element of an array into another one

Tags: c, arrays

Is there a way in C to copy all the elements of an array into another one, without parsing all the elements of the array to copy? Could I use pointers? Because I know that a function can automatically take a certain number of element of an array just saying the index of the first element, so probably (?) I can do something similar...

For example if I have this two arrays:

```
int array[10];
int tocopy[3];
```

and I say something like:

```
array[0] = tocopy
```

it automatically fill also *array[1]* and *array[2]*

Is this possible?

Comment: No, it's a syntax error, and other elements are not automatically filled. Try `memcpy` or `memmove` to copy several elements in one instruction. But you must be very careful not to exceed array bounds: C offers no protection against yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `memmove()` or, if the arrays do not overlap, `memcpy()`:

```
void *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

For example:

```
memmove(array, tocopy, sizeof(tocopy);
```

would be like doing:

```
array[0] = tocopy[0];
array[1] = tocopy[1];
array[2] = tocopy[2];
```

---

## Note

As suggested in the comments, be also aware of not to exceed the array bounds when using these functions, i.e.: either reading or writing outside the memory allocated for the array.

Comment: Just be careful when using such functions as they can become hacking attack vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet might well be a `for` loop. You can make a function to "hide" details

```
void arrcopy(int *restrict dst, int dstindex, const int *restrict src, int srcindex, int len) {
    for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
        dst[dstindex + k] = src[srcindex + k];
    }
}
```

And you'd call it like this, for your example of copying the 1st three elements of `tocopy` to the 1st three elements of `array`

```
arrcopy(array, 0, tocopy, 0, 3); // array[0,1,2] = tocopy[0,1,2]
```

To copy the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th elements of `tocopy` (assuming they exist) to elements 6th, 7th, and 8th of `array` you would call the function like this

```
arrcopy(array, 5, tocopy, 1, 3); // array[5,6,7] = tocopy[1,2,3]
```

Of course, always make sure to not go over array bounds.